# Start Qt app right after initial windows startup

Tags: windows, qt, authentication, gina

I need to start my application before the windows login form displays, and the login process should be done within the application. How is this possible with the Qt framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to customize the Windows graphical identification and authentication (GINA) using only Qt. GINA is a component of some Microsoft Windows operating systems that provides secure authentication and interactive logon services. You will have to implement a custom GINA, which involves providing implementation for a set of native API calls. More information on this topic is available at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication).